# How to render all unknown properties from array of objects except some in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi guys I'm trying to render all properties except some from an array of objects in react js. Each object has a property of id, title, state, answered, selected, expanded, and also some other properties that are unknown or might change in the future.
I want to always render all except these: id, selected and expanded. The component has to be reusable so I don't  want to write each property's name out. Is it possible?

```
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'fdsfsdfs',
    state: 'fsdfsd',
    viewed: 503,
    answered: 207,
    folder: 'fsdfds',
    created: '2017-11-28',
    validUntil: '2019-04-01',
    createdBy: 'user1',
    selected: false,
    expanded: false
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Ffdsf',
    state: 'Rfsdfdsa',
    viewed: 803,
    answered: 112,
    folder: 'fdsfsd',
    created: '2017-11-11',
    validUntil: '2018-07-12',
    createdBy: 'user2',
    selected: false,
    expanded: false
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'dsfsdf',
    state: 'f',
    viewed: 503,
    answered: 207,
    folder: 'fsdfsd',
    created: '2017-11-10',
    validUntil: '2019-04-01',
    createdBy: 'user3',
    selected: false,
    expanded: false
  },
] ...


return (
   <tr>
     <td>...All properties except Id, selected, expanded</td>
  <tr>
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below code should solve your problem:

```
import React from "react";
import SearchBar from "./SearchBar";

const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'fdsfsdfs',
    state: 'fsdfsd',
    viewed: 503,
    answered: 207,
    folder: 'fsdfds',
    created: '2017-11-28',
    validUntil: '2019-04-01',
    createdBy: 'user1',
    selected: false,
    expanded: false
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Ffdsf',
    state: 'Rfsdfdsa',
    viewed: 803,
    answered: 112,
    folder: 'fdsfsd',
    created: '2017-11-11',
    validUntil: '2018-07-12',
    createdBy: 'user2',
    selected: false,
    expanded: false
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'dsfsdf',
    state: 'f',
    viewed: 503,
    answered: 207,
    folder: 'fsdfsd',
    created: '2017-11-10',
    validUntil: '2019-04-01',
    createdBy: 'user3',
    selected: false,
    expanded: false
  },
]

const omittedProps = ["id", "selected", "expanded"];

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      {data.map(d => (
        Object.keys(d).map(prop => (
          !omittedProps.includes(prop) && (
            <tr>
              <td>{d[prop]}</td>
            </tr>
          )
        ))
      ))}
    </>
  )
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Object.keys()`, `filter()` and `map()` to get it done.

```js
return (
    <>
    {data.map(item => 
        <tr key={item.id}>
            {Object.keys(item).filter(key => ['id', 'selected', 'expanded'].indexOf(key) !== -1).map(fkey => <td>{item[fkey]}</td>)}
        <tr>
    )}
    </>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.keys()` and `filter()` to get the visible columns as below function to get visible props.

```js
 const data = [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'fdsfsdfs',
        state: 'fsdfsd',
        viewed: 503,
        answered: 207,
        folder: 'fsdfds',
        created: '2017-11-28',
        validUntil: '2019-04-01',
        createdBy: 'user1',
        selected: false,
        expanded: false
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Ffdsf',
        state: 'Rfsdfdsa',
        viewed: 803,
        answered: 112,
        folder: 'fdsfsd',
        created: '2017-11-11',
        validUntil: '2018-07-12',
        createdBy: 'user2',
        selected: false,
        expanded: false
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: 'dsfsdf',
        state: 'f',
        viewed: 503,
        answered: 207,
        folder: 'fsdfsd',
        created: '2017-11-10',
        validUntil: '2019-04-01',
        createdBy: 'user3',
        selected: false,
        expanded: false
      },
    ]

    const skip = ['id', 'selected', 'expanded'];

    const propsToShow = Object.keys(data[0]).filter((item) => !skip.includes(item));

    console.log(propsToShow);
```